# Google App Maker - Directory info based on email from other datasource

Tags: google-directory-api, google-app-maker

Working on an app where I'm getting the email address of a user from Google Sheets.

I would like to use that email address to surface the Full Name and Thumbnail Photo from the directory.

[Screenshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvEDv.png) - email & names hidden to protect user data

So far, when I try to link the two I get the First photo from Directory for all the users.

Any ideas how the two can be linked, as the Directory doesn't support adding new relations?

Comment: Can you please provide your code, and any data suitable for explaining the example more completely?

Comment: I don't have any written code as I tried to do it only using data binding. I have two data sources - MyDataSource & Directory. From MyDataSource I bring email, manager in an Accordion and I'm trying to bring from the Directory the corresponding Full Name and Thumbnail for each record. Unfortunately it either doesn't bring anything or it brings the 1st item in the directory and displays the same one for each of the following record rather than respective pictures and names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new Calculated Model
2. In the Datasources tab, in the
   Server Script add the code below.
3. **Be sure to correct the Model and Field names to match yours!**

.

```
//Get the Spreadsheet Data
var spreadsheetData = app.models.MySpreadsheetSource.newQuery().run();
var combinedData = []; // Place to store output for calculated model
spreadsheetData.forEach(function(record){ //iterate the ss data
  var query = app.models.Directory.newQuery(); //start a query for directory
  query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = record.email; //set the query for the email
  var dirRecord = query.run()[0]; //get the one record

  //make a new record for the calculated model
  var newRecord = app.models.Directory_Spreadsheet.newRecord(); 
  //add the data from both SS and Directory models
  newRecord.Email = record.email; //from ss
  newRecord.address = record.address;
  newRecord.Full_Name = dirRecord.FullName; //from Directory
  newRecord.Thumbnail = dirRecord.ThumbnailPhotoUrl;
  //Add More Fields

  combinedData.push(newRecord); //add to output
});
return combinedData; //return the combine object
```

You can use this Datasource in your Accordion to display the combined data.

Comment: This worked James thanks so much! On the flipside, though it takes roughly 30 - 45 seconds to load the data - filters and searches no longer working despite updating all the bindings to the new datasource. Nonetheless I'll play around and see what can be done to combine the functionality. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you are just displaying the one record you can get the email from the spreadsheet and then do something like this.

The Page or a Panel with the datasource set to Directory and Label widgets with the text field bond to the field you want to show.

[image] 
[image]

AFTER you get the email from the spreadsheet, assuming you are returning it to the client side, use:

```
app.datasources.Directory.query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = emailFromSpreadsheet;
app.datasources.Directory.load();
```

Comment: Thanks James. I have an Accordion for the list of people and all the details in the Accordion come from the Spreadsheet data. The only items I'm trying to bring from Directory are the Thumbnail and Full Name - items which are not included in the Spreadsheet data. I'm still a beginner with coding - where exactly do I add the code snippet you suggested above? I re-wrote it like this to find the EmailfromSpreadsheet field - app.datasources.Directory.query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = app.datasources.MySpreadsheetSource.item.Email_Address then directory.load as above

Comment: Create a Calculated model and on the Datasources Tab add the code below to the Server Script. See other answer as it's too long for a comment.